# Twitter bot is using the wrong account

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Trying to develop a bot account on twitter. However, I cannot understand how to connect the account I want to use to the code. It is currently connected to my personal account and I suspect it is because that is the account that the developer account is under. I understand that this might not be the best place for this. If so, would you be kind enough to direct me where I can post this.

Comment: May I recommend you to improve your question. You can follow article here.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A twitter bot account acts on the developer's account behalf. They are identical. If you want to run the bot under a different account you need to create the API credentials under that other account.